# Is there a way to install emoji and use them in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, 18.10, emoji

I'm very new to the world of Ubuntu as you may tell. I'm not a fan of Google's (new) Noto emoji and I dislike the gaps Firefox's emoji font, Twemoji Mozilla has. That's why I'd like for them to all be the same. I want to know how to install EmojiOne or Twemoji.

Also, https://getemoji.com/ shows me that Noto emoji has the cold face and hot face emoji but the emoji picker found in Text Editor doesn't seem to have them. Any reason why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Cold face and hot face emoji are too new...

https://emojipedia.org/freezing-face/

> noto-emoji committed on 11 Aug 2018: Update NotoColorEmoji font with
>   new U11 images.

UPDATE:
Font package has new Emojis
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-noto-color-emoji/+bug/1788256

Problem with GTK Emoji picker.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/

Comment: I thought emoji could update automatically on Ubuntu. Am I wrong?